# Is it possible to have python open a terminal and write to it?

Tags: python, linux, gnome-terminal

For example, if I have this code:

```
subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal'])
```

Is it possible to have python output strings to that specific terminal that was just opened? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible... But what do you want to *do*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, but it is easier to have a custom process running in the subordinate terminal. For example, given `sserv.py` from the [example server in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcp-server-example) the command:

```
 gnome-terminal -e "python ./sserv.py"
```

will happily chat on port 9999 with you. Given a more complex `sserv.py` it could do anything you want (anything terminalish, that is).

Answer (score 2):

I think that [PExpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) might do this for you:

> Pexpect is basically a pattern
>   matching system. It runs programs and
>   watches output. When output matches a
>   given pattern Pexpect can respond as
>   if a human were typing responses.
>   Pexpect can be used for automation,
>   testing, and screen scraping. Pexpect
>   can be used for automating interactive
>   console applications such as ssh, ftp,
>   passwd, telnet, etc. It can also be
>   used to control web applications via
>   `lynx`, `w3m`, or some other
>   text-based web browser. Pexpect is
>   pure Python. Unlike other Expect-like
>   modules for Python Pexpect does not
>   require TCL or Expect nor does it
>   require C extensions to be compiled.
>   It should work on any platform that
>   supports the standard Python pty
>   module.

Comment: @Arafangion Actually PExpect _DOES_ support writing, and does it well.
It can even write to PAM password inputs, which usually do not work with typical stdin. PExpect imitates tty device IIRC

Comment: What about child.sendline() etc in http://pexpect.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pexpect/trunk/pexpect/examples/monitor.py?revision=498&view=markup?

Comment: @Daniel: Well, ok, yes, you can use PExpect to do writing, but why would you without doing any reading?